# RESTfull way to check if a user can connect with Slim

Tags: angularjs, connection, slim, restful-architecture

I have a SLim API and I'm using it in my ANgularJS app to access my DB like this (for example):

My controller:

```
$scope.testDatabaseItems = function(){
    $http.get(pathApi + 'items').success(function(data) {
        $log.info("succes!");
        $log.log(data);
        $scope.items=data;
    })
    .error(function (data, status){
        $log.error("error!");
        $log.log(data);
    });
};
```

My Slim app:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'config/config.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->get('/items', 'getItems');
$app->get('/items/{id:\d+}', 'getItemById');
$app->post('/new_user', 'addUser');
$app->get('/users', 'getUsers');

$app->run();

function DB_Connection() {
    global $dbparams;
    $dbhost = $dbparams['host'];
    $dbuser = $dbparams['user'];
    $dbpass = $dbparams['password'];
    $dbname = $dbparams['dbname'];
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}

function getItems() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM aj_items";
    try {
        $db = DB_Connection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $list = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($list);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}

?>
```

My problem is that I want to call my Slim app to check if a username and a password works (connection), but I want a RESTfull API and I reed somewhere that in a RESTfull API, I most always use either one of those: GET, POST, DELETE or PUT.

I don't see which one I can use since I just check some information and compare it with password_verify(). I know that I want to return 2 particular field if it works, but I'm not sure what to do if I still want my API to be considered RESTfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an application environment involving a Restful API, it is recommended to use JSON Web Tokens (JWT) for passing claims between parties.

Using [firebase/php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) within your Slim app.

```
composer require firebase/php-jwt
```

Then in your routes

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->get('/authenticate', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $key = "example_key";
    $token = array(
        "iss" => "http://example.org",
        "aud" => "http://example.com",
        "iat" => 1356999524,
        "nbf" => 1357000000
    );
    $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);
    $response->getBody->write(json_encode(['token' => $jwt]));
    return $response;
});


$app->get('/items', function (Request $request, Response $response){
    $key = "example_key";
    $token = $request->getHeader('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION');
    if (!empty($token) && is_array($token)) {
        $token = trim(str_replace('Bearer', '', $token[0]));
        if (JWT::decode($token, $key, ['HS256'])) {
            // User authentication successful
        } else {
            // User authentication failed
        }
    }
});
?>
```

Now you'll need to cache the JWT returned by `/authenticate` somewhere.  It's a good idea to use window.sessionStorage as data persisted lives until the browser tab is closed, [more on cookies vs tokens](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/)

```
$scope.testDatabaseItems = function(){
  $http.get(pathApi + 'authenticate')
    .then(function (response){
        if (response.data.token !== undefined && response.data.token.length) {
            $window.sessionStorage.token = response.data.token;
        }
    }, function (reason){
        console.log(reason);
    }
  );
};
```

At this point you will need to tell Angular to catch every request, adding an Authorization header containing the JWT before sending it to the server using an interceptor:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
}]);

app.factory('AuthInterceptor', ['$q', '$window', function ($q, $window) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
      }
      return config;
    },
    response: function (response) {
      return response || $q.when(response);
    }
  };
}]);
```

No further configuration should be needed.  Before your application calls `/items`, it will first need to call `/authenticate` after which, the JWT should be sent as an Authorization header on every subsequent request until the browser window is closed or `$window.sessionStorage.token` is reset manually.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm not shure that I understand. Where am I suppose to check if the user has given a correct username/password? Where is password_verify()?

Comment: My question was where should I put the code to check if the user can connect? Should I have a authentication function that i call with (GET, POST or PUT) api/authentication? Should that function get the password for the given username and then compare it to the given password to see if it fits and then return some informations or a message that tell that it didn't work? Hould all thet be done inside my API function or does it go against being RESTful? Should I use GET, POST or PUT?

Comment: I have a few questions; 1---what is $key = "example_key"; 2---With this, I wouldn't need to have something like a session key in my database? 3--- Could I store the username and the privilege inside the cookie and would it be safe? 4--- If someone tries to change the contente of the token, would it notice it make the token invalide?